# How do I unlock a gold chest on a floating island?

Tags: terraria-console

My floating island has a locked gold chest, and I've updated to version 1.2. How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 2):

#### Gold chests require a [Golden Key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golden_Key)

Gold chests on floating islands and in the [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon) require a key to open. These keys can be found in the Dungeon, either in normal chests, from killing [Dungeon Slimes](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Slime), as a rare drop from any other Dungeon enemy (1/65 chance), or in [Pots](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pot) in the Dungeon (1/40 chance).

#### But I thought floating island chests were unlocked?

For the initial release of Console Terraria, chests on floating islands were locked. It wasn't until the [1.02 Console update](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_Version_history) (making it the equivalent of the PC 1.2.1.2 update) that floating island chests were no longer locked.

#### But I'm fully updated!

Features such as chests and their contents are determined at the time a world is generated, and are never altered by updates. **If you generated your world in an older version of Terraria, those chests will still be locked after an update.** To be sure you get all the features for the newest version of Terraria, particularly features of the world (e.g. [Crimson](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson) or the [Snow Biome](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Snow_biome)), you'll need to generate a new world after you update.